# Display Firestore Data in NextJS Server side component using the App Router

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, next.js, app-router

I'm trying to fetch a collection from firestore using a nextjs Server Side Component in the App Router. I can get the data and it shows my collections in the console.log() but when i try to display it on the page, it just says undefined.

I tried a function to call the collection from firestore as follows:

```
`export const getUsers = () => {
    projectFirestore.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            return {
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data()
            }
        });
    });
}`
```

and tried to display as such:

```
`  const BlogPage = async () => {

   const  users = getUsers();

   console.log(users)


  return <main>
<h5>{users && users.map((company)=>{
  return company.companyName
    })}</h5> 
    <h1>The Blog</h1>
    <p><Link href="/blog/post-1">Post 1</Link></p>
    <p><Link href="/blog/post-2">Post 2</Link></p>

  </main>
}`
```

The data displays in the console.log in vs code but not in the browser console, and doesn't display on page either.

Answer (score 0):

To fix these issues, I;ve tried an approach to modify both the `getUsers` function and the `BlogPage` component.

1. **Modify `getUsers` Function**: Convert `getUsers` into an async function that returns a promise. This promise should resolve with the array of user data.

   ```js
   export const getUsers = async () => {
       const querySnapshot = await projectFirestore.collection("users").get();
       return querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
           id: doc.id,
           ...doc.data()
       }));
   };
   ```
2. **Update `BlogPage` Component**: Use `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps` in Next.js to fetch data server-side. This ensures that the data is available before the page is rendered.

   ```js
   export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
       const users = await getUsers();
       return {
           props: { users }, // will be passed to the page component as props
       };
   }

   const BlogPage = ({ users }) => {
       return (
           <main>
               <h5>{users && users.map(user => <div key={user.id}>{user.companyName}</div>)}</h5>
               <h1>The Blog</h1>
               {/* ... other content ... */}
           </main>
       );
   };

   export default BlogPage;
   ```

   Here I've changed the followings:

   - `getServerSideProps` fetches the users before the page is rendered.
   - The fetched users are passed as props to the `BlogPage` component.
   - The component then renders the users' data.